# AVAssetWriter: preview recorded .mp4 before calling `finishWriting`?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avkit

I am using `AVAssetWriter` to record a video (with audio) form iOS camera. Everything works great.

I now want to allow the user to preview the video before `saving`, meaning, before calling `finishWriting` on the `AVAssetWriter` instance.

My original thought was to copy the current file the writer is writing to during recoding to a preview url, and then use another `AVAssetWriter` to finalize that file and then play it.

However, I am not sure how to properly initialize a second `AVAssetWriter` for preview purposes, so I can call `finishWriting` on it at the preview url...

Anyone knows how I could implement preview functionality to allow a user to preview the currently recorded `mp4` before calling `finishWriting`?

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone knows how I could implement preview functionality to allow a user to preview the currently recorded mp4 before calling finishWriting?

You must call `finishWriting` in order to have a viewable mp4 file.

So call `finishWriting`, let the user preview the resulting file and then decide whether to delete it or keep it.

Comment: I need to keep the asset writer unfinished until the user saves. I need to preview the current video while the original asset writer is still not finished.

Comment: Why does the writer need to be unfinished? So you can continue recording?

Comment: Yes. The objective is to allow the user to preview the recorded video before a final save. So the user might want to continue recording after previewing what has been recorded already.

Comment: In that case you could start recording to a new file and then merge the two together when finished. You could do this using a combination of `AVMutableComposition` and `AVAssetExportSession` (possibly at the expense of an audio transcode, although you should be able to avoid the video transcode).